# How do you install Cliqz browser?

Tags: software-installation, repository, browser, 18.04

Is it possible to install the "secure and no-compromise browser" [Cliqz](https://cliqz.com/) in Ubuntu? PPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update April 2020: [Cliqz will not be maintained anymore](https://cliqz.com/en/magazine/farewell-from-cliqz).**

A **64-bit Debian compatible package** is provided that you can install from the **custom ppa/repository**, tested in Ubuntu **16.04 and 18.04**:

**Add the Cliqz repository** **signing key** to be able to verify downloaded packages

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4E0C443A
```

**Add the Cliqz repository**

```
echo deb http://repository.cliqz.com/dist/debian-release stable main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cliqz.list
```

**Update the list of available packages**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install Cliqz**

```
sudo apt-get install cliqz
```

Alternatively, you can download and install the **[deb package](https://cdn.cliqz.com/browser-f/download/linux/cliqz.en-US.release.x86_64.deb) manually**, but be aware that you will **not benefit from updates**:

**Disclaimer:** They do not officially support Cliqz for Linux, this means that:

1. Cliqz for Linux is not as well tested as for other operating systems.
2. User support will not give priority to requests about Cliqz for Linux.

Source: [Cliqz.com](https://cliqz.com/en/desktop/cliqz-for-linux)